# Java Generics & operator

Tags: java, generics

I am facing some difficulty to understand an expression in java generics.
Please help on this:

```
public interface Inter {
    <T extends Enum<T> & FunctionalInterface> String getString();
}
```

Comment: It looks like a useless declaration of the type parameter `T`.

Comment: Thanks rgettman for the response. To be honest, I want to know what & means in this expression and how it works.

Comment: It represents an intersection type.

Comment: Thank you Jacob G for the answer. If possible can you tell a practical use of intersection type. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have given is legal, but useless.

It is useless for two reasons:

1. You have defined a generic type, T, as part of the method declaration that must implement the `Enum<T>` interface as well as the `FunctionalInterface` interface. However you haven't then used that type anywhere in the method's signature (i.e. arguments or return type) so it is effectively ignored.
2. Having an interface implement 'FunctionalInterface' is possible, but certainly not it's intended use. It is designed to be an annotation to an interface, not an interface itself.

You could make this combination work:

```
public interface Inter {
    <T extends Enum<T> & FunctionalInterface> String getString(T value);
}

static class InterImpl implements Inter {
    @Override
    public <T extends Enum<T> & FunctionalInterface> String getString(T value) {
        return value.name();
    }
}

enum EnumImpl implements FunctionalInterface {
    A, B, C;

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterImpl impl = new InterImpl();
    System.out.println(impl.getString(EnumImpl.B));
}
```

You'll see that the `EnumImpl` enumeration implemements `Enum` and `FunctionalInterface` so it can be used as an argument to `getString`.

So that's an explanation but, frankly, I can't think of any useful use case for such a piece of code.